# ScrollView not surrounding entire RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview

What I did was I added a bunch of `TextViews` programmatically, but now the `ScrollView` won't resize to fit all the new `TextViews` created in the `onCreate()` method.

onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);

    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        TextView number = new TextView(this);
        number.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        Log.i("i", Integer.toString(i));
        number.setLayoutParams(lp);
        number.setY(i / 2.54f * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
        relativeLayout.addView(number);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Is there any way to make the `ScrollView` fit everything inside the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: I think height of your `relativelayout` is `wrap_content` which will use space which needed for your total space of all textview height. make it `match_parent` and check.

Comment: Tried and didn't change

Comment: can you show image of screen?

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9b18dsovvUSDn5LVGYEJDD2KUwQKgUmq-EFN_FUEfU5RkIvWpz-n4oZpAoNEcC3V9wrKiTleVG_6fOZSdE2BKV1rlx2y

Comment: I am running your code, will put image of it.

Comment: I think it is showing in full screen, and you are taking about space in left and top it is padding you have put in relative layout.

Comment: I removed padding, but problem persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87051/discussion-between-shvet-and-silver2049).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Add this to your code,

```
 RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 TextView tv1 = new Button(this);
 tv1.setText("Hello");
 tv1.setLayoutParams(lp);
 tv1.setId(1);
 rLayout.addView(tv1);


 for(int i=1;i<25;i++)
 {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tv = new Button(this);
    tv.setText("Hello "+i+1);
    newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i);
    tv.setLayoutParams(newParams);
    tv.setId(2);
    rLayout.addView(tv);
 }
```

Comment: Try adding text view to your RelativeLayout through XML rather than the code. If it scrolls this way then there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: I tried and it worked, so I'm not sure what's wrong with my code